# UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput with more TextFields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uialertview

Its possible add more TextFields to UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput?
How could i do?
Or there is other possibility?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this is possible you can do it like this

```
 UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here!" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI – As I said before: altering UIAlertViews view hierarchy was explicitly forbidden. Now it will be impossible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7

Comment: Fairplay (Needed to use more characters)