# UIActivityIndicatorView not displaying in UIAlertView - iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I need to `UIActivityIndicatorView` in `UIAlertView` when loading. But `UIActivityIndicatorView` is not displaying when I add this with [UIActivityIndicatorView not displaying in UIAlertView - iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981040/uiactivityindicatorview-not-displaying-in-uialertview-ios7) in ***iOS 7***. And this is working good in iOS 6 & lowest versions. Below is my code.

Is there any solution ? . thanks.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\nloading.." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.frame= CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37);
activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

[alertView addSubview:activityIndicator];

[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 4):

Apple deprecated `addSubview` method in case of `UIAlertView`. So you can't add any subviews any more to AlertView, for example : activity indicator or some progress bar.

Here you can look at my question where people share custom Alerts which will support adding controls

[UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do customization with `UIAlertView`

Read this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView-SW1)

Best way is create custom UIView which look/feature like UIAlertView and add your activity indicator on this view.

Comment: If we create a UIView popover and keyboard comes over that UIView