# add UIActivityView on UIAlertView, but nothing displays on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7

I used code below to add UIActivityView on UIAlertView

```
UIAlertView * messageBox = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Connecting to App Store..."
                                                      message: @"\n\n\n"
                                                     delegate: nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];



UIActivityIndicatorView *aActivity=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

[messageBox addSubview:aActivity];
[aActivity setHidden:false];
[aActivity startAnimating];
[messageBox show];
```

it works well on ios 5,6 but on ios7 UIActivityIndicatorView does not display.
I changed `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge` to `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray`

```
UIActivityIndicatorViewWhite
```

None works

Your comments are welcome

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIActivityIndicatorView not displaying in UIAlertView - iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981040/uiactivityindicatorview-not-displaying-in-uialertview-ios7)

Comment: Please search or at least look at the related questions before posting your question.

Comment: From iOS 7 apple restrict the user to add subview to alertview to maintain the standard of it's  UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify an alert view like you used to. The internal behavior has changed, and this is no longer possible the way you did. You will either have to roll your own implementation of alert view, or take an open source implementation, such as [CXAlertView](https://github.com/ChrisXu1221/CXAlertView).