# How to disable a UIAlertView button with ios 7?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a simple view with a button linked with *"showAlert"* method. When I click on this button, it displays a UIAlertView.

Before, with ios 6, I was using the following code to disable a UIAlertView button :

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender
{
    myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Retour" otherButtonTitles:@"Button1", @"Button2", @"Button3", @"Button4", nil];
    [myAlert show];

    for(UIView *aView in myAlert.subviews)
    {
        if ([[[aView class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIAlertButton"])
        {
            UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)aView;
            if ([aButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button2"])
                aButton.enabled = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, with ios 7, it does not work... Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `iOS7` it's not possible to add or manipulate the subviews or a `UIAlertView`, you need to create your own, sorry.

Subclass `UIView` to create your own `UIAlertView` or use a 3rd party library.

Comment: pfff... Why this regression ? Thanks for your fast answer Antonio.

Comment: Yep, annoying... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a subview to `UIAlertView` is not possible from iOS 7.

The only way is to go for a custom `UIView` subclass which can act as `UIAlertView`.

[Github](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7) answer may get you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable 1st other Button of **UIAlertView**  using delegate method

```
-(BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    return NO;
}
```

works in ios 7 also.

Comment: Thanks Viruss, but I need to be able to disable sometimes the first button, sometimes the second, or some other buttons, according to its name.

Comment: @Erzékiel: no you can only disable first btn with this method.

Comment: @Virussmca i want also change the title of first button how can i do this please suggesst some things which will work on ios 6 and as well with ios 7