# UIActivityIndicatorView not showing on UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to add an activity indicator with some informational text to show network activity, in this case, a webservice call. My alert view shows properly during the web service call, but I cannot get the activity indicator view to show on the alert view.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    NSString *loadingText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loading %@ gauges...", [self stateIdentifier]];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:loadingText delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,200);

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:
                                         CGRectMake(roundf((screenRect.size.width - 50) / 2),
                                                    roundf((screenRect.size.height - 50) / 2),50,50)];
    spinner.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [alert addSubview:spinner];

    [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:alert];

    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    spinner.hidden = NO;
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [alert show];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        stateGauges = [[GaugeList alloc] initWithStateIdentifier:stateIdentifier andType:nil];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: `UIAlertView` doesn't support adding subviews, especially under iOS 7.

Comment: So, what might be a solution? Especially to support iOS7?

Comment: Don't use `UIAlertView`. Look into other solutions such as https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD?source=cc

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
[alert setValue:spinner forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

to get custom content in a standard alert view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show alertView and activityIndicator in Main thread,

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [spinner startAnimating];
    [alert show];
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on iOS 7

[UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7)

Use custom alertview, Try this

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD