# Entered text not showing in UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have an app i'm trying to port over to iOS 7. As there are no longer any textfields in iOS 7 `UIAlertViews`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7)) I have to resort to using 2 `UIViews` managed by 1 `ViewController.` I didn't use nib files and just program the UI from code.

When the app is started, the second `UIView` is stacked on top of the first one, it has a `UITextField` that takes in a user input. This code works in iOS 7 but does not work on iOS 6 devices.

In an iOS 6 device, when I tap on the textfield in the 2nd `UIView`, the keyboard appears. However when I enter something into the textfield, no characters appear. I even tried to `NSLog` the characters entered by the keyboard and got `NULL` which means no text is entered!

The code is as follows for the primary ViewController:

```
//View1 : UIView
View1 *aView1;
[aView1 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,40,280,200) title:promptMsg]
[self.view addSubview:aView1];
```

Inside the View1.m:

```
(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect) aRect title:(NSString*) promptStr{
self = [super initWithFrame:aRect];
UITextField *userField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,a,b)];
[self addSubview:userField];
```

Does any know what has changed in iOS 7 that 'allows' this behaviour? IS it a bug in iOS 7 or the SDK?

Comment: If you only need to have a text field in your alert view, why don't you just use `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` as the view's `alertViewStyle` property (available since iOS 5) and `textFieldAtIndex:` to customize the text field?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I know this but my old code extended the UIAlertView to have up to 3 textfields so I needed something like a view :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code i did not see any text you are setting, you are just allocating for example refer below:-

```
(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect) aRect title:(NSString*) promptStr{
self = [super initWithFrame:aRect];
UITextField *userField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,a,b)];
userField.text=@"yourText"; // here setting the text
[self addSubview:userField];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did a userField.text = @"somerandomtext"; but i still can't type on my iOS 6 device.

Comment: try this code and check  UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 6.0f, 278.0f, 32.0f)];
[txtField setPlaceholder:@"My placeholder"];
[txtField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]];
[txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[txtField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[txtField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[txtField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[txtField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either.. thanks. I can see the placeholder text, my cursor but when i type nothing goes into the text field.