# Change alert view title font in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, fonts, uialertview, title

I searched all over the net but couldn't find a solution to get this working under iOS 7. I read that iOS 7 really limited the customization of alert views somehow. (I don't fully understand what is meant under this). Anyways, the question is: How could I change the font of the title text of an alert view under iOS 7 and later?

Cheers!

Comment: Learn how to search the net! I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21635414/1971013) immediately.

Comment: I looked at the link, I read that already and that is why I asked the question. I am looking for a workaround, not another answer saying why you should not do it.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here, UIAlertView class you need to use as it is. There is no property for setting font. You need to develop new class works as UIAlertView and then use it to your app. [This will help you to choose suitable alertview for your application](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=alertview)

Answer (score 0):

Either use an [existing third-party](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) alert, or walk through the `UIAlertView`'s subviews until you find `UILabel` objects and try to set their `font` property.  Not sure if the latter will work, but it's a common trick to make style changes to UIKit objects.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, can you give me an example for the subviews method?