# Alert view does not disappear [iOS]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have created a custom alert view in which I created custom buttons and removed the default buttons. When I click the custom buttons, the alert view does not disappear. Please help me solve this problem. I am using the following code,

```
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
UILabel *lbladdblock=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,25,100,30)];
[alertView addSubview:lbladdblockname];
```

Comment: Share your code here.

Comment: UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil                                                                message:nil delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];

               

            UILabel *lbladdblock=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,25,100,30)];
           [alertView addSubview:lbladdblockname];

Comment: Show the code when you tap on the button.

Comment: Where do you declare and use the custom buttons?

Comment: -(void)gotoWelcomeScreen{
    // profileInfoViewController *profile= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileInfo"];
    scrollingViewController *profile= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"scroller"];
    
    
    profile.userImagePath=regUserPhoto;
    profile.phonenum=regPhNumber;
    profile.selfregistrationId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",registeredid ];
    
    
    [self presentModalViewController:profile animated:YES];
    
}

Comment: the view is transferred when i clickthe label but alert view is not dis appear

Comment: If the cancel button and other button, both are nil, how do you plan to make the alert view disappear?

Comment: i want to change design of the button so i create custom button

Comment: https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Answer (score 1):

1.include your .h file : UIAlertViewDelegate

2.please follow below implementation...

```
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
[alertView show];
UILabel *lbladdblock=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,25,100,30)];
[alertView addSubview:lbladdblockname];    
[self performSelector:@selector(dismiss:) withObject:alert1 afterDelay:1.0];
```

the dismiss method will be...

```
-(void)dismiss:(UIAlertView*)alert
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Or you wants to custom view than use

```
 UIAlertView*testAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 140)];


UIButton*testButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 40)];

[testButton setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[testAlert addSubview:testButton];
 [testAlert show];

-(void)someAction

{
[testAlert removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: i am using this code but alert view is dis appear after delay .its not wait until i click the label

Comment: hey i edit my answer check hope it will help

Comment: Thanks mokujin. your first method works for me:)

Answer (score 1):

If your class is subclass of UIAlertView then you can dismiss it by calling this method.

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];
```

you can use **self** in place of **alert** if you are using this method inside of class.

Answer (score 1):

To work around this issue, you do like this:

define `alertView` in header, then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UILabel *lbladdblock=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,30)];
    [lbladdblock setText:@"custom Message"];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setTitle:@"Dismiss!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissMe) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [alertView addSubview:lbladdblock];
    [alertView addSubview:btn];

    [alertView show];
}

 -(void)dismissMe
{
    [alertview dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Also, AFAIK `addSubView` to `alertView` is impossible in ios7 so your code will work for previous versions only. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7).

*Since you are not using built in features of UIAlertView (passing nil in all params)You should prefer some custom alert view. See the sample alert views in link.*

Hope it helps!