# How to resize UIAlertView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

Currently I'm using this code but it doesn't work in iOS 7. It works fine in iOS 6:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];

[alertView show];

- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
   [alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(alertView.frame.origin.x, alertView.frame.origin.y, alertView.frame.size.width, 200)];
 }
```

How can we resize in iOS 7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7)

Comment: Sounds different but the issue is the same, it's a private class so use a 3rd party solution if you need added functionality.

Comment: My issue in same class but in these used a private class ... It's work in iOS6 but not in iOS7

Comment: So you need to not use `UIAlertView` and use something else