# Make part of an alertview bold

Tags: ios, text, uialertview

Lets say I want to make only the text "Software" bold. Is there a way to achieve this without a custom alertview?

[image]

Comment: what is vsn? this is an ios app, if that is what you are asking

Comment: written in ios 7? in earlier versions it is possible but don't know how  to do with ios 7

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7

Comment: What do you @Esq have against a custom alert view? It's not hard to do, esp. in iOS 7 and later.

Comment: I don't really. But a simpler version of code that is understandable by all is always preffered

Answer (score 0):

```
self.subHeadingLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline];
```

Check out dynamic text in ios7 . it has six different font styles. There is a good article [here](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/07/ios7-day-by-day-day-12-dynamic-type-and-font-descriptors)

Comment: apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW65

Comment: How does that make _just the word "Software"_ bold, as the OP asked?

Comment: @matt he can set Software to be a subheading label. read the apple docs