# UITextField In UIAlert Input Not Working iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am currently using the following to use a popup alert which allows the user to set a delay in seconds;

The input itself works fine, but the number is not remembered, so if I put 5, or 10, when I press 'set' it just ignores that value and goes to instant recording again. here is the IBAction to call the setDelay, and below it, I have posted the Alertview

```
-(IBAction)setDelay:(id)sender
{
    // open a alert with text field,  OK and cancel button
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set delay in seconds" message:@" "
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Set", nil];





    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(14, 45, 255, 23);
    if(!delayTextField) {
        delayTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        delayTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
        delayTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        delayTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        delayTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

        delayTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        delayTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support

        delayTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;  // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
        delayTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        delayTextField.delegate = self;
        delayTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;   // has a clear 'x' button to the right
    }
    else 
    {
        delayTextField.text=@"";
    }

    alert.delegate=self;
    [alert addSubview:delayTextField];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

    [alert show];
    [alert release]; 
}
```

//

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag==100) 
    {
        if (buttonIndex!=alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
        {
            [self featureButtonPressed];
        }

    }
    else 
    {
        if (buttonIndex==alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
        {
            self.delayTextField.text=@"";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 7 you can't add subviews to `UIAlertView` anymore -
[UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7).

But if you need just simple `UITextField` in your `UIAlertView` you can just set `UIAlertView` style to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` and retrieve value from that field later. Eg.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set delay in seconds" message:@" "
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Set", nil];

alert.delegate=self;
[alert addSubview:delayTextField];
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[alert show];
```

then in your delegate method:

```
 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (alertView.tag==100) 
{
    if (buttonIndex!=alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        [self featureButtonPressed];
    }

}
else 
{
    if (buttonIndex==alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        UITextField *alertViewTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        //Do something with alertViewTextField.text value
    }
}

}
```

Comment: hmm, using that delagte method throws up an error 'use of undeclared identifier 'alert'

Comment: `change [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];` to `[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];`

Comment: That only then gives another warning unused variable 'alertViewTextField' and it doesn't work in the app either...

Comment: Firstly - warning is not an error. You have a warning because you have to do something with the declared `alertViewTextField`. You can check if text value of the UITextField has been updated with `NSLog(@"%@",alertViewTextField.text)`

Answer (score -1):

@Guferos answer is absolutetly correct. It doesn't work because iOS 7 doesnt support this.

But in case you need more than a simple TextView, you can use a framework such as https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

:)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not - see my above answer to @Guferos , I only need a simple way to retrieve the text value to confirm the delay selected by the user.