# How to Add Image/icon In dialog of titanium alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
  title: 'Enter text',
  style: Ti.UI.iOS.AlertDialogStyle.PLAIN_TEXT_INPUT,
  buttonNames: ['OK']
});
```

How I can add image/icon inside dialog in titanium alloy? Is there any property that I can add?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, you can't add an image to a `alertDialog` with Titanium.
Maybe it's possible with native : [UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7), but you should create a module to use it with Titanium.

Last solution is to create a custom view so you can customize everything you want.